# PHPMailer showing 'Message has been sent' with errors

Tags: php, openssl, phpmailer

I am using PHP Version 7.4.6. I downloaded the master version of PHPMailer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

A little background of my PHPMailer skill: I started using it three days ago to build a basic contact form for a simple contact website.

I received the following errors:

```
2020-05-22 16:51:05 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-05-22 16:51:05 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\xamp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php line 344]
2020-05-22 16:51:05 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [C:\xamp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php line 344]
2020-05-22 16:51:05 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) [C:\xamp\htdocs\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php line 344]
2020-05-22 16:51:05 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message has been sent
```

It shows me **'Message has been sent' accompany with error:**

> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL
>   routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Here's what I did/changed:

- I changed SMTPSecure to 'ttl' and Port to 587, to see more debug details. Then later changed it back to 'ssl' with 465 port.
- I added cacert.pem to my php.ini file, under openssl. I do always restart my Apache if any changes is made.
- I uncommented openssl.dll and opensll from php.ini file too.
- I checked the email address I am using via checktls.com. All greens for that.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require('PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php');
require('PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php');
require('PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer;

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                           // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';      // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'SENDER@gmail.com';    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';            // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                 // Enable TLS encryption;`PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 465;                   // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('SENDER@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('RECEIVER@gmail.com');    
    $mail->addReplyTo('RECEIVER@gmail.com');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Thank you for checking my code.

I am trying my best to read as much questions and answers given in this platform. But so far, I don't see any question that is facing the similar problem as I do now.

In the meanwhile, I will also continue looking for solution.

Cheers!

PS: Please don't mind if there is any spelling mistakes. I know some cares about it alot.

**Update (23/5/2020):** I sent over the php file to my friend. When he ran, he didn't receive any errors and the message is successfully sent from his side.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is getting as far as the "Message has been sent" is because although you wrapped it in a try/catch block, you have not told PHPMailer to throw exceptions, which it does not do by default — enable them by passing `true` to the constructor:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

If you really have the latest version of PHPMailer, then this line will cause a fatal error:

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

because that file is from an old version and no longer exists in PHPMailer.

You do indeed have a TLS problem. It's generally easier to debug TLS issues if you use `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587` as you'll get more debug output, in particular you will see the initial welcome banner from the SMTP server, which may reveal that your SMTP traffic is being intercepted and redirected to your hosting provider's server – and TLS is quite correctly refusing on the basis that its host name does not match what you were expecting.

I also recommend checking the connection using `openssl s_client`, as described in the troubleshooting guide linked from your error message, as that will eliminate your PHP config as the source of the problem.

Comment: I passed the 'true' in just now. Can I comment out the require line for PHPMailerAutoload?  Is the SMTP Server welcome banner looks something like: SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a16sm8538884pfl.167 - gsmtp"

Comment: Checked the connection using openssl s_client....all return with value of 1.

Comment: Hi.. I sent over the php file to my friend. When he ran, he didn't receive any errors and the message was successfully sent from his side. But I don't know why is it so.